# How to make a duration slider for a camera view in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a time duration component for a camera view like this in react native (please see the image below).

[image]

Is there a library that I could use if not, can you help how could I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this question since I manage to solved it.

I used [React Native Snap Carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) to make it work.